# Trying to iframe a website in html, won't display webpage

Tags: html, iframe

I'm new to coding, trying to get https://www.timeanddate.com/ to show up in an iframe with html.  I'm not trying to do anything fancy, I just want the site to show up in the iframe.  I have a few other sites that I already have working, just having an issue with this one.

I have done some searching, and found that I may not be able to display this site due to them denying embedding on other sites.

Just asking for some assistance with some code to get this to work, if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is becaused https://timeanddate.com site has the X-Frame-Options header set to SAMEORIGIN.
What this means is that the page can only be iframed on a page the resides on the same domain.

As an example https://timeanddate.com/test could have an IFrame containing the main site on https://timeanddate.com, because they are both from the timeanddate.com domain.

[Mozillas documentation for X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)